# Operations in nested loops within variables of filename format in R

Tags: r, loops, nested

The following code runs fine in R,and I got those coding by using 'disp' function in nested loop (SID, session) of matlab to do this trick.

```
....
S09_06<- read.csv("09_06.csv", header=TRUE,sep=",")
S10_01<- read.csv(file="10_01.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
...
```

So now the coding is combination of R + matlab, which is not so efficient actually.

There should be some ways to make it possible in R?

I've tried coding as follows with little modifications according the possible solution found in the internet several times already,

```
SID = c(....9, 10,....)
S = 1:6

for (value in SID){
  if (value < 10)
  for (value in S){
  paste0("S0",SID,"_0",S)  = read.csv(file = paste("0",SID,"_0", S, ".csv"), header=TRUE,sep=",")
  }else{
  paste0("S",SID,"_0",S)  = read.csv(file = paste("0",SID,"_0", S, ".csv"), header=TRUE,sep=",")
  }

}
```

However, the error message below shows every time,

"Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument"

How to make the operation work?

Thank you.

Comment: [Don't ever create d1 d2 d3, ..., dn in the first place. Create a list d with n elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Both , @ Parfait @ Uwe

Because there are hundreds of steps behind read.csv, and the difficulty of nested loops in R, drove me to turn to matlab for making these tricks work instead.

Although I got the results I want already, but it's like a semi-automatic coding. Every step related to loops needs to modify in matlab again when adding some new participants and put it back in R to run.

There should be some ways to manipulate all the codes in R sorely, to make the more than 100 thousands lines in R less and efficiently.

Every value needs to be calculated individually under different conditions before running ANOVA or Ancova. Or do you think it's better to be dealt on list basis?

For example, like missing or error rate of each participants based on the logical judgment of combination from different columns?

I can only make it work with R + matlab, but there should be some ways to deal with R solely.

That's why I started this question and Hope there will be some solutions.

Any comments will be appreciated.

Thank you and Have a nice day : )

Comment: Because the hundreds of nested loops that couldn't be coded in R, need to turn to matlab coding solely to make  "real automatic" coding, instead of "semi-automatic" coding : )  Need to say goodbye to R now. However, R plotting is still excellent than others : )

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a list of data frames by first building a vector of file names and passing them into an `lapply` or `sapply` call. Below uses `sapply` to generate a named (vs. unnamed) data frame list.

```
# CREATE VECTOR OF FILE NAMES (PASSING TWO VECTORS)
filenames <- as.vector(sapply(SID, 
                              function(x,y) paste0("S", ifelse(x < 10, 
                                                               paste0("0", x),
                                                               paste(x)), 
                                                   "_0", y),
                              S)
                      )

# CREATE NAMED LIST OF DATA FRAMES (PASSING ONE VECTOR) 
df_list <- sapply(filenames, function(i) {
                     fname <- paste0(substr(i, 2, nchar(i)),".csv")
                     read.csv(fname, header=TRUE, sep=",")
                  }, simplify=FALSE)

# ACCESS INDIVIDUAL DATA FRAMES    
df_list$S09_01  
df_list$S09_02
df_list$S09_03
...
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait, the df_list did make as a nested list with SID and S as mentioned. However, the content inside each .csv couldn't be read....all become "A data.frame with 0 rows and 1 column" in Value column when viewing df_list. and "No data available in table" when viewing into df_list$SID_S.  There should be a way to deal with nested loop puzzle and do some easy operation like read.csv here in R. Let's try and keep some faith in R still : )

Comment: I updated code passing your original args of *header* and *sep* which I thought was redundant being defaults but may differ in your language/region settings.

Comment: Thank you, @Parfait. After restarting R, your codes is working. Now I can move forward to further steps like select necessary columns, replace some values and so on that dealt with R+ Matlab before : )

Comment: Yes, I pressed the up icon for several times and it shows "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Sorry for that I have 11 only now...But I do appreciate your nice codes for me to retrieve some confidence in R : ) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

This question touches several issues:

1. How to read a large number of csv files in one go,
2. How to create a vector of filenames from 2 integer input vectors in the proper format.

Item 1. has been asked and answered many times before and is also the core of [Parfait's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57946154/3817004).

This answer focuses on Item 2.

As an added complexity, the filenames are following the scheme `"09_06.csv"`, `"10_01.csv"` (including the file extension) while the resulting data.frames are to be named `"S09_06"`, `"S10_01"` (with a leading `"S"` but without the file extension).

The creation of basenames (without prefix and file extension) in the proper format can be simplified by using `outer()` and `sprintf()`:

```
SID = c(9, 10)
S = 1:6
outer(SID, S, sprintf, fmt = "%02i_%02i")
```

> ```
>      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]   
> [1,] "09_01" "09_02" "09_03" "09_04" "09_05" "09_06"
> [2,] "10_01" "10_02" "10_03" "10_04" "10_05" "10_06"
> ```

The conversion specifier `%02i` denotes a field width of 2 characters and that the output is to be padded with leading `0`s.

Now, the list of data.frames can be created by 3 lines of code:

```
basenames <- outer(SID, S, sprintf, fmt = "%02i_%02i")
df_list <- lapply(paste0(basenames, ".csv"), read.csv, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
names(df_list) <- paste0("S", basenames)
```

*Just for demonstration* and in order to avoid to create many csv files beforehand, the `print()` function is used instead of `read.csv()`:

```
basenames <- outer(SID, S, sprintf, fmt = "%02i_%02i")
df_list <- lapply(paste0(basenames, ".csv"), print) # just for demonstration
names(df_list) <- paste0("S", basenames)
df_list
```

> ```
> $S09_01
> [1] "09_01.csv"
>
> $S10_01
> [1] "10_01.csv"
>
> $S09_02
> [1] "09_02.csv"
>
> $S10_02
> [1] "10_02.csv"
>
> $S09_03
> [1] "09_03.csv"
>
> $S10_03
> [1] "10_03.csv"
>
> $S09_04
> [1] "09_04.csv"
>
> $S10_04
> [1] "10_04.csv"
>
> $S09_05
> [1] "09_05.csv"
>
> $S10_05
> [1] "10_05.csv"
>
> $S09_06
> [1] "09_06.csv"
>
> $S10_06
> [1] "10_06.csv"
> ```

#### Create *one* data.frame

The OP has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944738/operations-in-nested-loops-within-variables-of-filename-format-in-r/57950698#comment102332827_57946154) that he wants to "select necessary columns, replace some values". This sounds as if all files have an identical structure, i.e., the same number, order, names, and type of columns.

*If all files do have the same structure*, I would combine them in *one* large data.frame. This is easier to handle than to apply all operations on a list of data.frames.

This is what I would do with my preferred tools:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
SID = c(9, 10)
S = 1:6
filenames <-CJ(SID, S)[, sprintf("%02i_%02i.csv", SID, S)]
lapply(filenames, fread) %>% 
  set_names(filenames) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "file")
```

> ```
>          file V1 V2          V3
>  1: 09_01.csv  Y 39 -0.83562861
>  2: 09_01.csv  D  1  1.59528080
>  3: 09_02.csv  V 74  1.51178117
>  4: 09_02.csv  N  7  0.38984324
>  5: 09_03.csv  O 84  0.59390132
>  6: 09_03.csv  A 35  0.91897737
>  7: 09_04.csv  F 40 -1.47075238
>  8: 09_04.csv  Y 44 -0.47815006
>  9: 09_05.csv  B 18 -0.41499456
> 10: 09_05.csv  M 22 -0.39428995
> 11: 09_06.csv  G 81 -1.16657055
> 12: 09_06.csv  K 13 -1.06559058
> 13: 10_01.csv  N 59  0.48742905
> 14: 10_01.csv  R 51  0.73832471
> 15: 10_02.csv  I 37 -0.04493361
> 16: 10_02.csv  Y 34 -0.01619026
> 17: 10_03.csv  O 28 -1.98935170
> 18: 10_03.csv  T 20  0.61982575
> 19: 10_04.csv  Z 51 -0.10278773
> 20: 10_04.csv  G 42  0.38767161
> 21: 10_05.csv  S 70  0.76317575
> 22: 10_05.csv  H 87 -0.16452360
> 23: 10_06.csv  W 84 -0.11234621
> 24: 10_06.csv  N 29  0.88110773
>          file V1 V2          V3
> ```

Note that the first column contains the filename from which the row originated.

#### Data

Sample files were created by

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
SID = c(9, 10)
S = 1:6
fn <- outer(SID, S, sprintf, fmt = "%02i_%02i.csv")
set.seed(1L)
nr = 2L
dfl <- replicate(
  length(SID)*length(S), 
  data.frame(V1 = sample(LETTERS, nr), V2 = sample.int(100, nr), V3 = rnorm(nr)),
  simplify = FALSE
  ) %>% 
  set_names(fn) 
lapply(fn, function(x) fwrite(dfl[[x]], file = x))
```

Comment: Thank you, @Uwe. Your explanation is easy to understand and same result got with your codes for the .csv namelist(SID_S). However, the content of each .csv couldn't be read when running 'df_list <- lapply(paste0(basenames, ".csv"), read.csv, header = TRUE, sep = ",")'. Error message : "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection". df_list@Parfait could make it : )

Comment: That was caused because I had overlooked that your filenames are *not* prefixed by `"S"`. I have corrected this.

Comment: Thank you, @Uwa. We are the guys who always want to make coding working : ) However, my data format is UTF-16, which is not supported by fread. Endless nested loops could be easily made by matlab effortlessly and apparently it's not the case in R... Thank you again for noticing what steps to take for the next. Have a nice day : )

Comment: Oh, I see. UTF-16 seems to have been an issue (https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2560) indeed but according to https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2435 the development version 1.12.3 of data.table has fixed the issue, IIUC.